# Cheat for Pokemon Emerald causes the game to freeze on the Android GBA Emulator?

Tags: emulation, cheats, pokemon-third-generation

I started playing Emerald few weeks back. I wanted to use cheats here. I had put the master code and the master ball code which works absolutely fine. But whenever I use pokemon code nothing happens. Keep in mind, I play On my Android phone in the GBA emulator (not the John lite version). Once I put the Pokémon cheat and then use the PC in Pokémon Center the game just freezes.

I don't know what the problem is but when I searched about it many people claim that they had it worked on their cell phones.

The code I'm using is for Bulbasaur: 83007CF6 0001, which I obtained off the supercheats.com site

Comment: Hi @user3627194, welcome to Arqade! It would help if you could tell us which code exactly is giving you trouble, where you got the code from (so we can cross-reference to make sure you're entering the code correctly), and list the steps you're taking when you enter it :)

Comment: @Robotnik it is available on supercheat.com

Comment: @Robotnik for eg. Balbusar = 83007CF6 0001

Comment: Thanks, I've added those to your question :). I'll test it when I get home - which GBA emulator are you using? is it just called 'Android GBA Emulator'?

Comment: @Robotnik it can easily be found here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.van.gba

Comment: @Robotnik what gba emulator do you use for cell phone? Do all the cheats work fine in it?

Comment: In the past I've used Tiger GBA, but I've never tried using the cheats on Android. I've used VisualBoy Advance on PC with cheats before.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you did after inserting the code? Some codes used to freeze GBA on my PC so I had to be very careful and disable the code after I found (and caught) pokemon I wanted.

Comment: @Jerry I disabled all code except 2 master code and 1 pokemon code

Comment: @Jerry once I put the pokemon code and then go in grass to catch then the battle loading starts then the screen goes black. Is it that only specific codes work?

Comment: @user3627194 Hard to say. These codes are tricky, and it looks like you are doing it right to me. I guess the code doesn't work too well with the emulator.

Comment: Maybe, is just a matter of contacting the emulator creator. Have you tried on other phone. Could be specific issue related to your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

What probably happened to you is a "Bad Egg" has appeared in your pc, causing your game to freeze.
Basically, bad eggs have a chance to appear when you cheat and getting rid of them isn't that easy.
If you want to research more about bad eggs, you can read about them more in this link.
[Bad Egg](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bad_Egg)

Here you can see more about how to get rid of them.
[Getting Rid of Bad Eggs in Pokémon Emerald](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al6a63vgNjQ)